# Check if a URL scheme is registered on iOS or Android in Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, cordova-3

I want to check if a particular app is installed and if it is installed, invoke it.

AFAIK, the way to do it is to check if the custom url scheme of the app is registered and use that url to launch the app.

Is there a way for me to do this in my Cordova app?

To be very specific I want to check if the Google Maps application is installed on iOS and if it is, launch it with its custom url else show the default Apple maps.

This url : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme : shows how to do it in Objective-C, but how do I do it in Javascript in my Cordova app?

I could not find any plugin to achieve the same. Other questions on SO deal with either doing this from a native app or JS on a regular website (in the browser). The most common work-around is to try launching and use a timeout to see if the app launch failed and still my app is running. This is pretty unclean. Access to the iOS API `canOpenURL` through JS would be best.

Hints?

Comment: I don't know Cordova, but could you make an extension that calls out to a native iOS method?

Comment: @meaning-matters Technically yes. That is what would be a Cordova plugin. I am not proficient in Objective-C or Android dev. So I am trying to see if either the Cordova platform itself has this feature or if there is an existing plugin which does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cordova does not ship with this feature. There is a plugin which implements it for iOS, though.

- https://github.com/philbot5000/CanOpen

I did not find anything for Android yet, but I do not think this would be hard to do in native Android Code. Even if you are not proficient with Objective-C or Java and never intend to write fully native apps, you should learn some basics if you want to build apps with Cordova.

Small and simple plugins are really easy to do. Read the docs and have a look at the code of some simple plugins to see how it is done. For example the source code of the one above or of the one below is really simple and straightforward to understand:

- https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin