# Angular Deep Link (Universal Link) to redirect on app if installed or store

Tags: ios, angular, deeplink

I have a problem with deep link. On ios if app not installed, the system show a popup with "Safari cannot open page because wrong path". When the modal is closed, a new one appears which correctly asks to open the store.This I know happens because initially, if the app is not installed, you still try to go to my-app.

This is my script:

```
    window.location.href = 'my-app://';
     setTimeout( function(){
     window.location.href = "app-store-link";
   }, 500);
```

Any suggestions? is there a workaround without using external services?
Thanks to all.

Comment: You can try a similar solution as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23763120/check-if-a-url-scheme-is-registered-on-ios-or-android-in-cordova)

Comment: Thanks @Eldar, but your solution use a cordova plugin. I dont have cordova

Comment: Ah sorry. Misunderstood badly. You are already using a workaround, original one has smaller value for timeout value.

Comment: Exactly, just that ios before opening the app store, shows a system modal that says that the first path (in this case my-app //) is not valid.This workaround worked until recently :/